# Open dropdown list, when click on input vue js

Tags: vue.js

I need to open the md-select dropdown when clicking on input. I read many articles and count not find the solution.

Below is the code

```js
                <md-select
                  v-if="isDropdown"
                  v-model="submittedBy"
                  name="submittedBy"
                  id="submittedBy"
                >
                <md-option
                  :value="`${lead.firstName} ${lead.lastName}`"
                  v-for="lead in getUsersNoPagination"
                  :key="lead.id"
                  >{{ lead.firstName }} {{ lead.lastName }}</md-option
                >
              </md-select>
                
              <md-input v-on:click="showDropdown" v-if="isInput" 
v-model="submittedBy"></md-input>
```

Vue method code to hide and show the input type text and dropdown list.
Inititialy **isDropdown:false** and **isInput : true,**

```
showDropdown(){
  this.isDropdown =true;
  this.isInput =  false;
},
showInput(){
  this.isDropdown =false;
  this.isInput =  true;
},
```

please help to solve

Comment: What does `showDropdown` do? In that do you set `isDropdown` to true?

Comment: updated the code, please have a look now

Comment: I think the problem is that the moment you select on the `md-input` component, `isInput` becomes false so anything that `showDropdown` would do, wouldn't work. Maybe have another variable that makes `md-input` disappear